# Plot complex path (essentially a 2D path) expressed in one real parameter

Tags: plotting, complex

Consider a complex path expressed in one real parameter, such as
$$f(\alpha)=\frac{1}{e^{i \alpha} + 1},$$
which is a Möbius transformation of the unit circle. I know I can expand it all out and use the parametric plot, but it is cumbersome and not very easy (sometimes practically impossible) to do so.

Therefore, I want to know if there is some plotting function specifically designed for this. (I searched for it in the documentation but did not find it; sorry if it's all obvious.)

Comment: The first argument of `ParametricPlot` should be `{Re@#, Im@#} &@f[x]` -- not so cumbersome, I think.

Comment: @Anon Thank you for the answer, I never thought of that nice solution. Anyway, I find it hard to get the code working. I've tried a couple of possibilities like `ParametricPlot[{Re@#, Im@#} & (1 / (Cos[u] + I Sin[u] + 1)), {u, 0, 2 Pi}]`, `ParametricPlot[{Re@#, Im@#} & (1 / (Exp[I u] + 1)), {u, 0, 2 Pi}]` and `ParametricPlot[{Re[1/(Cos[u] + I Sin[u] + 1)], 
  Im[1/(Cos[u] + I Sin[u] + 1)]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}]`. None of them worked. The only thing that produced a result was `ParametricPlot[{Re[Cos[u] + I Sin[u]], Im[Cos[u] + I Sin[u]]}, {u, 0, 
  2 Pi}]`.

Comment: It's because you've omitted `@`.

Comment: @Anon Oops sorry, those are typos. Inserting `@` does not seem to help though, and note there's simply no `@` `ParametricPlot[{Re[1/(Cos[u] + I Sin[u] + 1)], Im[1/(Cos[u] + I Sin[u] + 1)]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}]`, it is explicit. Maybe you could open up a Mathematica session and give them a try? At least they don't work in my 9.0.1.0 student edition.

Comment: I mean, the problem is with the complexity of the function, not the syntax. Since the very simple `ParametricPlot[{Re[Cos[u] + I Sin[u]], Im[Cos[u] + I Sin[u]]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}]` _does_ work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is *not* with the complexity of the function, but with the fact that your function diverges. Consider:

```
f[u_, a_] := 1./(Exp[I u] + a);
Manipulate[ParametricPlot[{Re@#, Im@#} &@f[u, a], {u, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotRange -> All], 
          {a, 0, 2}]
```

As long as you stay away from values of $a$ near 1, the plot is reasonable. As $a$ approaches 1, the function diverges to +/-$\infty$.

Comment: So I was trapped by my stupid example, into which I didn't give much thinking... Okay.

Comment: Well the real part is a constant 1/2 so you get a vertical line that goes to infinity at Pi or -Pi. Otherwise Presentations has a ComplexCurve[f[t], {tmin, tmax}]  routine for plotting complex curves, which you would have to email me to obtain more information.